# LIST<> AddRange throwing ArgumentException

Tags: c#, exception, list

I have a particular method that is occasionally crashing with an ArgumentException:

```
Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.:
at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.CopyTo(T[] array, Int32 arrayIndex)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
```

The code that is causing this crash looks something like this:

```
List<MyType> objects = new List<MyType>(100);
objects = FindObjects(someParam);
objects.AddRange(FindObjects(someOtherParam);
```

According to MSDN, List<>.AddRange() should automatically resize itself as needed:

> *If the new Count  (the current Count  plus the size of the collection) will be greater than Capacity, the capacity of the List<(Of <(T>)>) is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array to accommodate the new elements, and the existing elements are copied to the new array before the new elements are added.*

Can someone think of a circumstance in which AddRange could throw this type of exception?

---

Edit:

In response to questions about the FindObjects() method.  It basically looks something like this:

```
List<MyObject> retObjs = new List<MyObject>();

foreach(MyObject obj in objectList)
{
   if(someCondition)
       retObj.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: What does `FindObjects` return? Also, why do you initialize `objects` then promptly reassign it on the next line?

Comment: When you add an item, it checks if the size is large enough, if not it resizes the internal array it uses.  When using multiple threads however, one may check, get a false and resize the array, the next thread reads that there is enough space and doesn't resize, then they both reach the actual `this._items[this._size++] = item;` code at the same time...causing the latter thread blows up.  When Jon says `List<T>` isn't thread safe in the answer below, this is one of the things `List<T>` doesn't handle.

Comment: I didn't write the code, I am simply debugging the issue.  There are plenty of weird things that maintainers find when rummaging around :)

Comment: What happens when you just call FindObjects(someOtherParam)?  I presume that provides the list as expected?

Comment: Correct.  I myself haven't been able to reproduce this problem, but someone provided a stack trace of this issue occurring, so I know it happened at least once.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you trying to update the same list from multiple threads? That could cause problems... `List<T>` isn't safe for multiple writers.

Comment: The FindObjects() method itself instantiates a new List<> object, populates it and returns it.  They are all single-threaded, so I don't think there are any chances for multiple threads to be working on the List.

Comment: @Tim: Then I can't see why it would happen. See if you can come up with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. If we can reproduce it, we should be able to fix it.

Comment: This is more or less what I was hoping to hear.  I haven't been able to reproduce this problem, and it seems to me like it shouldn't ever happen.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something before outright rejecting it as an issue.

Comment: The problem you have is that it definitely has happened, as you say you have a stack trace to prove it.  I think a concurrency problem is most likely — you sure it's not a background task started by a UI button, for example, and the user is clicking it twice in quick succession?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not sure, but why not just remove the size declaration on your List initialization?

```
List`<MyType>` list = new List`<MyType>`
```

Comment: Because that initialization is promptly discarded. It doesn't even *need* to be initialized in this way.