# List<T>: Clear; AddRange; Add; Delete; ect.. causes System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, exception

I'm getting the following exception when trying to clear a list.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=-2146233080
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Array.Clear(Array array, Int32 index, Int32 length)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Clear()
       at SystemFilterFactory.ResetSystemFilters() in d:\Source\SystemFilterFactory.cs:line 57
  InnerException:
```

The real exception wasn't being shown which is the base of that list is giving the following exception

**Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.**

Answer (score 9):

I actually ended up finding the cause from this post just before posting my question
[LIST<> AddRange throwing ArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593267/list-addrange-throwing-argumentexception)

However that took quite a bit more searching since i wasn't expecting the real problem to be with the list.

It turns out that since List is not thread safe, doing operations on the list where it will be changed in size on multiple threads at the same time can make it so that nothing on that list works correctly.

So for doing operations on the list make sure that you are doing it in a thread safe way.

Comment: Should be pretty common knowledge. There was great fanfare when .net 4 came out with the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace

Comment: Not just _"where it will be changed in size"_. All operations are unsafe when another can modify the list.

Comment: @Henk Holterman That's true none of them are safe, however the ones which change the size of the list can stuff up the underlying array (i'm assuming that the size becomes too small in some cases)
That way no operations will work on the array.

Comment: [This is a great article](http://mailinator.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html) that demonstrates very neatly *just how **weird*** the side effects of concurrent access to thread-unsafe data structures can be.