# Is a lock needed when every thread will be accessing a unique element/ID in a static shared list?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a shared C# `public static List<long>` used in a multi-threaded application.

Upon **login**, a check for the user's  "ID" (which is a unique 'long' 
 number) is performed to determine if it is contained within this shared list, if not, then the user's ID will be **added** to this shared list.

Upon **logout**, this user's ID will be **removed** from the shared list (assume a check to see if the user's ID is in the list prior to removal). User has no ability/visibility to access their ID.

**Question**: Is a lock for accessing the shared list object needed in the above scenario? If so, what sequence of execution will result in unexpected data?

Byrd requested code. Here is some generic code reflecting the above question/scenario:

```
public class MyApp
{
    public static readonly object _userIDs = new object();
}

void Login(long uniqueUserID)
{
    if (_userIDs.Contains(uniqueUserID) == false)
    {
        _userIDs.Add(uniqueUserID);
    }
}

void LogOut(long uniqueUserID)
{
    if (_userIDs.Contains(uniqueUserID) == true)
    {
        _userIDs.Remove(uniqueUserID);
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `List<T>` states whether or not it can be used safely from multiple threads.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, any sequence of execution you can envision that would give the above usage data issues? If so, I would be interested to hear your point of view. Thanks!

Comment: Again, see the relevant section of the documentation on thread safety for that type.  It will tell you what sequences of execution are supported and will function properly, and what ones will not.

Comment: I had, it doesn't note a sequence of execution for my given my usage that would cause issues. It states the following:

'Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List<T>, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation..'

Comment: So now you know exactly what sequence of operations you need to perform for it to break, just perform multiple writes, or a read and a write, at the same time from multiple threads and it will break.  You know that the only safe multithreaded access is all threads reading and no writers.

Comment: Unless the note, "issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read" pertains to all usages. If so, is the issue that the memory space used to store the list and the operations of writing while a read is being made, regardless if the list element in question is not overlapping between the write and read, is the underlying issue?

Comment: ok, so then based off of MSDN, any thread could make any number of writes all day long without issues, provided that no reads are made, and we should be okay.

Comment: Any *single* thread can make any number of writes all day long without issues provided that no reads or writes are made by any other thread, and you will be okay.

Comment: Would `ConcurrentBag` be worth considering as an alternate @MoeHoward?

Comment: `Is a lock for accessing the shared list object needed in the above scenario?` Yes. `If so, what sequence of execution will result in unexpected data?` Any situation in which there are two writers at the same time, or a writer and a reader at the same time can cause the issue. _Note that it is a race condition - so it won't necessarily occur **all** of the time, but it will happen eventually._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIST<> AddRange throwing ArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593267/list-addrange-throwing-argumentexception)

Comment: @mjwills a `ConcurrentDictionary` would be better than a `ConcurrentBag` you just ignore the value and it is a psudo `ConcurrentHashSet` which is what the OP really needs anyway.

Comment: @mjwills - I think you hit a key points there 'mjwills'. The unexpected data scenario doesn't seem to be the issue, it's the concurrence access that is the issue given your Possible duplicate response is what seems to make the most sense as I couldn't see a sequence of gets and sets that would cause unexpected data as in the cases where multiple threads were updating a shared counting integer without a lock. Thanks, and thank you too also Servy.

Comment: @Scott, yes, 'ConcurrentDictionary' seems to one way to go, but it seems 'ConcurrentBag'  would work better logically given my usage as it has a "TryTake()" method which would be perfect for LogOut() usage, no need to check and then remove.... Thank you.

Comment: @Scott, seems that 'ConcurrentDictionary' is the way to go, TryTake() just gets the last entered item... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-threaded application that's accessing the same list this could be disastrous unless you lock it first.

Well when you are iterating through a list in general, without a thread, you can't do this for instance.

```
List<object> dataList = new List<object>(){"foo","bar","my","list"}
foreach(object o in dataList){
     dataList.Remove(o);
}
```

Not sure what the exact error is but, you're changing the value of the object you are iterating through while you are iterating through it. It will crash.

If you add it to a "to remove later" list then have a thread remove the data later that should be fine. Something like this...

```
List<object> dataList = new List<object>(){"foo","bar","my","list"};
List<object> toRemoveLater = new List<object>();
foreach(object o in dataList){
     toRemoveLater.Add(o);
}
foreach(object o in toRemoveLater ){
     dataList.Remove(o);
}
```

In a multi-threaded application though you'll most likely get a concurrent modification error since you are changing the value in memory while another thread is iterating through it.

However, there are some thread safe lists that will force other threads to wait their turn with the memory. It depends what you are doing exactly seeing your code might help.

Comment: Added generic code example demonstrating usage. Important note: there is no overlapping of 'uniqueUserID' values over all threads (meaing, every thread will has its own ID, you can think of this as "threadID" for that matter).

Comment: So what you are trying to do will only throw errors if you are reading from this static list anywhere in the program. Let's say someone logs out at close to the same time someone else logs in. There was a contains(object) and an add(object) and now it will have a concurrent modification error. I suggest you add the "Logged out users" into a separate List<long> idToRemove and let a slave thread pick up the remove function when there are no more login requests or logout request. That way you are only adding login IDs to the list and it won't crash.